# PHP updating large database

Tags: php, database, pdo

I have a large database (28k entries in this particular table one table) and I need to append some HTML tags to the front and back of every column in a table.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    if(!$conn)
    {
        echo "Error in connecting to the database.";
    }
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );  

    $query = $conn->query("SELECT `id`, `introtext` FROM *TABLE* WHERE id >= 41155");
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    //For each row in the table
    while($row = $query->fetch())
    {
        $introtext = '<span class="*SPAN CLASS*">' . $row->introtext . '</span>';
        $update_query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE *TABLE* SET introtext = ? WHERE id = ?");

        if ($query->execute(array($introtext, $row->id))) 
            echo $row->id . " Done <br>";
        else 
            echo $row->id . " Err<br>";
    }

} catch(PDOexception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

When I run the script, it outputs `41155 Done` 4132 times. I'm not sure the logic here, but any help to get this working is appreciated.

Comment: 28k is not large, and **don't** do this, add the html when you output the data

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't design the database or the way of accessing it. I just have to work around it. Anyways, I have to add a span class so that when the logic end gets to the database some CSS knows what to do.

Comment: This kind of time-consuming process should be written in a script and launched by a [shell_exec('your_script &')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function just like in [this ffmpeg example](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts)

Comment: Regardless, it already exists in this state and formatting and time would prohibit me changing it.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this would be a one-time task?

Comment: Shell scripts seem interesting... And yes, this is only a one time task for an archive table, so I'll hopefully never need to run this again. Would running this as a shell script fix the problem, or only make it run faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Dagon that the database is not the place for that (what if tomorrow you decide that `<span>` should wrap another HTML tag?).

Anyway, it sounds like a one-time operation, so I wouldn't use PHP. Just run a MySQL client (the command line  `mysql`, or Workbench, and use a query like this:

```
UPDATE *TABLE* 
SET introtext = CONCAT('<span class="*SPAN CLASS*">', introtext, '</span>') 
WHERE id >= 41155
```

One note about your current code: you're never executing the `UPDATE` query! You just `prepare` the statement, then instead of executing `$update_query`, you're executing `$query` again! That's why you're always printing the same id.

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something stupid. But yes, I'll try running it as a sql query first.